# The name 'TextBox1' does not exist in the current context(usually)

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, visual-studio

I am currently developing a website by visual studio c# language and right now I am working on the user password reset page design. The problem I met is that I want to add the control to the `textboxes` and `labels` by using basic `textbox.text = "";` method. But it keeps telling me it did not exist. I have searched a lot of solutions I am sure that:

1, It is the same name between the label name and the coding name.

2, There were no other same name pages since I was re-created another page with different names.

3, All these are added:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Mail;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Data;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;
```

Can anyone help? I confused here for a few days already:)

```
protected void SubmitButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string CS = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DBCS"].ConnectionString;
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(CS))
    {
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("spResetPassword", con);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

        SqlParameter paramUsername = new SqlParameter("@UserName", userTextBox.text);

        cmd.Parameters.Add(paramUsername);
        con.Open();
        SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        while (rdr.Read())
        {
            if (Convert.ToBoolean(rdr["ReaturnCode"]))
            {
                SendPasswordResetEmail(rdr["Email"].ToString(), TextBox1.Text, rdr["UniqueId"].ToString());
                msgLabel.Text = "An reset password Email has sent to your Email address.";
            }
            else
            {
                msgLabel.Text = "username not found!";
            }
      }
 }
```

Comment: Meaning that all the userTextBox, msgLabel are shows does not exist in the current context

Comment: Since all assigned server controls doesn't bound in code-behind, check if the class name inside .designer.aspx.cs exactly match with .aspx.cs, then ensure code-behind file referenced with same name in ASPX page.

Comment: I thought textbox1 has a lower case t, "textBox1.Text"

Comment: Do you have the html?

Comment: namespace testSiteV1.Account {
    
    
    public partial class ForgetPsw {
        
        /// <summary>
        /// PassRecover control.
        /// </summary>
        /// <remarks>
        /// Auto-generated field.
        /// To modify move field declaration from designer file to code-behind file.
        /// </remarks>
        protected global::System.Web.UI.WebControls.PasswordRecovery PassRecover;
    }
}

Comment: Thanks for your reply:) As it is shown above,
I think my .designer.aspx.cs is fine. It still shows error

Answer (score 0):

Does your textbox control have the following attribute?

```
runat="server"
```